# Mustache templates doesn't update with dropwizard

Tags: java, mustache, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard (0.8..) and mustache as the view template engine. I am trying to find a way that the templates going to be updated if I hit reload on the browser while developing. So far I didn't find any working way.

Is there some Option that I can/need to change?
Using IntelliJ as well as Java 1.8

Answer (score 1):

No is the short answer.

Dropwizard does a load of caching inside of [MustacheViewRenderer](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-views-mustache/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/views/mustache/MustacheViewRenderer.java), you could clone this class and remove the cache but you'd then face the problem that running dropwizard from IntelliJ means the mustache templates are all loaded from the target directory instead of your source directory, so you'd still need to copy them over for every change you make.